# Access redis locally on docker - docker compose

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have two containers, redis and web. I am trying to access the redis container from web. Nothing works. Below is my docker compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
      - /private/var/www/redis:/var/www/redis
    network_mode: host
  web:
    build:
      context: web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
      - "127.0.0.1:443:443"
      - "127.0.0.1:22:22"
    volumes:
      - /private/var/www/:/var/www/
    networks:
      - docker_web_network

networks:
  docker_web_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
         - subnet: 162.18.1.0/16
```

When I run `redis-cli` in the web container I get `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`.

Docker containers

```
Vs-MacBook-Pro:docker vn$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                NAMES
36ca1b626a68        docker_web          "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          127.0.0.1:22->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:80->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:443->443/tcp   docker_web_1
d6191f39385a        redis:alpine        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                                                               docker_redis_1
```

redis cli

```
root@36ca1b626a68:/var/www# redis-cli -h docker_redis_1 ping
Could not connect to Redis at docker_redis_1:6379: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using localhost in docker container is invalid as localhost means for container his own container so if you run redis-cli from within web container redis-cli is trying to find redis in web container instead of redis container.

U need to specify redis service name - docker (docker-compose's network to be more specific) will resolve for you service name to redis's container IP so you should use:

```
redis-cli -h redis ping
```

expected output is:

```
PONG
```

Edit:

That answer will only work if both services use same network mode so there are 2 ways:

1. Add network_mode:host to web service and then "localhost" for redis will be fine
2. Remove network_mode:host from redis and then "redis" domain will be fine

Comment: I added my docker redis container.

Comment: Please use command which I provided you as docker_redis_1 is not valid and "redis" host is valid - you need to use service name from docker-compose file.

Comment: `root@36ca1b626a68:/var/www# redis-cli -h redis ping
Could not connect to Redis at redis:6379: Name or service not known
`

Comment: Ah sure - please just remove network_mode: host from redis service and it will be fine. Or add network_mode:host to web service and then use "localhost" for redis's host